# Overriding the addtocart button for third-party api

Tags: api, addtocart, simple-product, sku

I am new to Magento2 and currently working on a project where some products can be custom-designed via a separate API. So when the add-to-cart button is clicked, instead of adding the product to the cart, it should take the SKU from the simple product (which contains the external productID) and send it to the API.

For the last couple of days I tried different methods I found online that supposedly would give me the SKU, though none of them seemed to work. In the end, I figured as on the button-press the ID of the simple product must be sent to the cart, it would be easiest if I could change the button behavior to use the ID to extract the SKU and create a redirect to the API with the information.
I just am at a loss as to how to get "into" the process of Magento.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add to cart button in product page coming from Catalog module with `product/view/addtocart.phtml` template file.

If you want to customization on addtocart template file in Magento 2, You can override `addtocart.phtml` file in your module by this way.

1. Create the `catalog_product_view.xml` file in your module on following place.

> app\code\Vendor\Extension\view\frontend\layout\catalog_product_view.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page layout="1column" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="product.info.addtocart">
            <action method="setTemplate">
                <argument name="template" xsi:type="string">Vendor_Extension::product/view/addtocart.phtml</argument>
            </action>
        </referenceBlock>
        <referenceBlock name="product.info.addtocart.additional">
            <action method="setTemplate">
                <argument name="template" xsi:type="string">Vendor_Extension::product/view/addtocart.phtml</argument>
            </action>
        </referenceBlock>
    </body>
</page>
```

2. Now you have to create template file `addtocart.phtml` in your module at below location,

> app\code\Vendor\Extension\view\frontend\templates\product\view\addtocart.phtml

3. Copy original template from Core Catalog module `addtocart.phtml` file and then do your customization.

Comment: Thanks that works. But I still struggle to get the sku of the simple product after configurations are selected. Any idea?

Comment: If answer help you, please upvote and accept as solutions.
If you have another issues, then please ask the separate question so other member can also help you.